# Ant Design integration in Universal React Redux Starter Kit

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, boilerplate, antd

I'm starting a new project on React and I want to use this stack:
React Router 4 + Redux + Universal Rendering + Ant Design

I have found that nice starter kit https://github.com/combine/universal-react-redux that cover most of my needs except it use Semantic UI not Ant Design

I'm trying to integrate Ant Design in it like I did on another working project following instructions of this article https://medium.com/@GeoffMiller/how-to-customize-ant-design-with-react-webpack-the-missing-guide-c6430f2db10f

When I try to use a Ant Design Button in the Home component, I have this error

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Button from './button';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Object.obj.(anonymous function) [as runInThisContext] (/Users/Arnaud/Documents/Tepee/src/universal-react-redux/node_modules/node-dev/lib/hook.js:30:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at nodeDevHook (/Users/Arnaud/Documents/Tepee/src/universal-react-redux/node_modules/node-dev/lib/hook.js:61:7)
    at require.extensions.(anonymous function) (/Users/Arnaud/Documents/Tepee/src/universal-react-redux/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .js] (/Users/Arnaud/Documents/Tepee/src/universal-react-redux/node_modules/node-dev/lib/hook.js:61:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
[ERROR] 00:14:04 SyntaxError
```

What I understand of the error is that babel is not used in this case (because import is not understood) but

1. I don't understand why it works for other librairies and not for antd
2. I have no idea how to fix this

Help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Check out Antd pro version all the above are embed. dva sorts you out router redux and redux store management. As for the dev tools we have roadhog which embeds webpack plugins

Comment: Thanks @chapskev but https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro is not an universal app (or I missed it) ?

Comment: What do you mean by not an universal app?

Comment: I mean that I do not have server side rendering (for SEO purpose) on ant-design-pro. When I show source of the page the <div id="root"></div> is "empty